# Adding a debugging col/row in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to add a manual column to make debugging MDX query results easier? For example, something like:

```
SELECT {
     DESCENDANTS(...),
     " --- end of descendants ---",
     ASCENDANTS(...)
} ON ROWS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, calulated members are the way. Take a look at the sample below where i have printed the current member, last member and next member

```
with member measures.CurrentName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.name

member measures.NextName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.nextmember.name

member measures.LastName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.prevmember.name
select {[Measures].[Internet Order Count],measures.CurrentName,measures.NextName,measures.LastName }
on 0,
[Product].[Product Line].[Product Line] on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Based on the comment below about adding a row

Here is a sample that adds row too.

```
with member measures.CurrentName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.name

member measures.NextName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.nextmember.name

member [Product].[Product Line].[CustomValue]
as 
"End of descendants"
member measures.LastName
as 
[Product].[Product Line].currentmember.prevmember.name

select {[Measures].[Internet Order Count],measures.CurrentName,measures.NextName,measures.LastName }
on 0,
{[Product].[Product Line].[Product Line],[Product].[Product Line].[CustomValue]} on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: ok but how would you add a row that says "" --- end of descendants ---" ? This isn't really about adding another `measure` it's about adding a debugging row/col (a dimension).

Comment: You missed the idea. I was not adding another measure there. I was adding a calculted member, although it was added to the measure hierarchy but as shown in the next example you can add it anywhere.